# multiple dictionary iteration python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary(d) in the format of

```
[
{'green': 'banana', 'yellow' : 'apple', 'red' : 'cake', 'blue': 
  [ 'id:xyz:abc:def::12128:htm/example/example2/example | number: 289038 | time: 200 hours'],
'computer': 'lorem ispsum', 'COF': 19},


{'green': 'banana', 'purple' : 'plum', 'gray' : 'screen', 'white': 
  [ 'id:xya:abo:dee::121548:htm/examplez/example26/examplelp | number: 289034 | time: 900 hours'],
'box': 'lorem ispsums', 'COF': 91},


{'green': 'monkey', 'orange' : 'oranges', 'clear' : 'candy', 'chevy': 
  [ 'id:pyz:kbc:qef::12178:htm/example8/example19/exampley | number: 289738 | time: 3 hours'],
'play': 'lorems ispsum', 'COF': 119},
```

I'm trying to iterate through this whole dictionary and if a key and value match print the rest of the dictionary but I get

```
"List indicies must be integers, not str"
```

When i use

```
(item for item in d if item["green"] == "banana").next()
```

Comment: So *at least one* of your `item` elements in `d` is **not** a dictionary.

Comment: I agree with Martijn's diagnosis. Also, you say `d` is a dictionary, but it isn't: it's a list. Are you clear on the distinction between the two?

Comment: Yes dictionary {}, list []. a misprint on me.

Answer (score 0):

```
generator_item = (item for item in d if isinstance(d, dict) and item["green"] == "banana")
generator_item.next()
```

Just calling .next() after you build the generator and don't save it to a specific value doesn't do anything useful